# How to generate a pdf whenever save the data?

Tags: html, node.js, pdf

I need to generate a PDF whenever submitting the data from a html form. But PDF should not be a image of html page. I have used node.js for my server implementations. All the data that I have inserted from fields in the form should be included in the PDF. Also, I have used mongodb as my database.

```js
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var outline=require('./schemas/outline');
var outcomes=require('./schemas/outcomes');


//making db connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/modulelist');
//checking db connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("connected to db");
});


//setting client location
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/client"));
//setting body parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());


//Insert modulelist data to db
app.post('/SaveModuleList',function(req,res){
    var mod=new outline(req.body);
    mod.save(function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            res.json(docs);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});

app.post('/SaveOutcomesList',function(req,res){
    var out=new outcomes(req.body);
    out.save(function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            res.json(docs);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});


app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server runing in port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Why you don't want image ? You can use jsPDF for generating pdf but that use html canvas for generating pdf

Comment: I don't want image of html because it's not give me a clear view. Just want to generate pdf. Yes. I have used jsPDF but it's not properly work for me